# How to add add/or for #states condition => value? In Drupal states

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'd like to see if I can check on multiple conditions...if fieldname is 35 OR 27 then make it required...

Is it possible to do multiple conditions in the Drupal 7 FAPI #states?

```
$form['field_fiscal_year'] = array(
      '#states' => array(
        // Only show this field when the 'select list' is either 35 or 27
        'required' => array(
          ':input[name="field_doc_type[und]"]' => array('value' => 35),
          ':input[name="field_doc_type[und]"]' => array('value' => 27),
        ),
              ));
```

Answer (score 4):

From http://api.drupal.org/comment/46038#comment-46038:

The proper way to do OR is:

```
<?php

 $form['field_two']['#states'] = array(

    'visible' => array(

      ':input[name="field_one[und]"]' => array(

        array('value' => '3'),

        array('value' => '4'),

      ),

    ),

  );

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

ORs currently aren't supported, there's been a [discussion](http://drupal.org/node/735528) going on for a while now.

The fix has been [committed to Drupal 7.13](http://drupal.org/node/1464758) but for now there are patches on the above page that will let you do ORs and XORs with states.